# PhantomJS not persisting localStorage consistently

Tags: phantomjs

I am trying to make an isolated test case to experiment with PhantomJS `localStorage` behavior, but in my testCase, localStorage does not appear to be persistent.

Here is the PhantomJS script:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open('http://localhost:8080/myapp/test.html', function() {
  var x;
  x = page.evaluate(function() {
    return localStorage.getItem("foo");
  });
  console.log(x);
  phantom.exit();
});
```

When test.html has a call to `localStorage.setItem("foo", "bar")` the script displays "bar" as i expect.  But when I remove the `localStorage.setItem` call from test.html, the script  prints out a blank line instead - even though the item should be in localStorage from the previous invocation.

From more complex tests on my real application, localStorage *is* persisting.  I'm not sure what the trigger is that makes changes to localStorage stick with PhantomJS.

I got identical results with PhantomJS 1.9.7 on Windows and 1.9.1 on Linux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may be timing-related.  If you exit phantom too quickly the changes to localStorage may not be persisted.  Changing `phantom.exit()` to `setTimeout(phantom.exit, 1500)` seemed to work.